# Python/Tkinter: Building a toolbar that provides edit cut, copy, paste commands

Tags: python, tkinter, clipboard, toolbar

I'm looking for suggestions on how one might implement a toolbar that provides edit cut, copy, paste commands using the Tkinter framework. I understand how to build a toolbar and bind the toolbar commands, but I'm confused over how the toolbar button bound commands will know which widget to apply the cut, copy, or paste action because the widget with edit activity will lose focus when the toolbar button is clicked. My first thought was to have each widget with potential edit activity set a global variable when the widget gains focus and have other widgets (without edit activity, eg. buttons, sliders, checkbox/radiobox, etc) clear this global variable. But this sounds complicated to maintain unless I build a framework of widgets that inherit this behavior.

Is there a simpler way to go about this or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the toolbar buttons to not take the focus; it's a configuration option and no UI guidelines I've ever seen have had toolbar buttons with focus. (Instead, the functionality is always available through some other keyboard-activatable mechanism, e.g., a hotkey combo.)

Comment: Donal: Thank you. For the benefit of other readers: Use widget.config( takefocus=False ) to prevent a toolbar widget from gaining focus. To determine the widget that currently has focus (from within the active window) use window.focus_get() where window is a variable containing a reference to your Tk() root window or currently active Toplevel window.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to maintain a big framework, you can create a single binding on the root widget for `<FocusIn>` and put all the logic in that binding. Or, use `focus_class` and bind to the class `all`.

Binding on the root will only affect children of the root, binding to `all` will affect all widgets in the entire app.  That only matters if you have more than one toplevel widget.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like a very powerful feature. Is the concept of class hard coded to widget type (Entry, Text, Button, etc) or can I create multiple named classes based on the same widget?

Comment: @Malcom: it's one of the best kept secrets of tk. The concept is called "bind tags". Look that up on google. The basic idea is, bindings are actually on tags, not widgets. It's just that widgets by default have a tag of the same name as the widget, plus one with the same name as the widget class, the top level window, and "all". You can add any other tags you want, reorder the tags that are there, or remove them entirely

Comment: You're blowing my mind! Getting my head around bind tags should destroy my productivity for the next few hours. How many more Tkinter secrets are you hiding from the rest of us? :)