# How to implement a toolstrip to my GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, toolstrip

I am creating a simple application to manage unknown words when learning a new language. The application is written in Python and I am using Tkinter to build the GUI.

[image: GUI]

As you can see, I am almost done - all I need is a toolstrip with several buttons on it, but it seems that there is no toolstrip widget in Tkinter. How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: Create a frame. Add some buttons.

Comment: ...as an alternative to a toolstrip? There must be a way to implement a toolstrip to a program.

Comment: I believe tkinter does not have any special widget, however PyQt has [QToolBar](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtoolbar.html) and [QMenuBar](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html) (depends whether you want icons or text as buttons in the toolstrip).

Comment: You can use the `Menu` widget for dropdown menus, but there is not widget to create a real toolstrip. You should indeed create a `Frame` and put it at the top of your GUI, put your widgets into it and that would have to serve as your toolstrip. You could of course design your own widget in `Tcl`, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: PyQt was what I needed.

Comment: Any toolbar widget requires the user to provide a sequence of toolbar images and corresponding toolbar functions to be called when an image is clicked.  Packing or gridding Buttons that display an image and call a function when clicked is pretty trivial.  The pad and other options can be used for detail placement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111049/python-tkinter-building-a-toolbar-that-provides-edit-cut-copy-paste-commands discusses the less obvious focus issues.  (I found this by searching SO for `[tkinter] Button toolbar`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no toolstrip widget when it comes to Tkinter.

You have three options:

**1)** If you want to continue building your application using Tkinter, you could create a frame at the top of your GUI and add some buttons into it, which would act as an alternative to a toolstrip.

**2)** You can design your own widget using [Tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/), which is definitely a lot of effort for a beginner.

**3)** You can start from scratch by switching to [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) which has [QToolBar](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtoolbar.html) and [QMenuBar](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html) (depending on whether you want icons or text as buttons in the toolstrip).

Comment: I'm not surprised there is no widget for it since option 1 is so trivial and easy.